# Unknown class XXXXX in Interface Builder file

Tags: ios, swift

I wrote two swift files.

```
// ViewController.swift
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

and

```
// ViewController2.swift
import UIKit

class ViewController2: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

My `Main.storyboard` looks like this.

[image: Main.storyboard]

When I run these programs, I get

```
2015-11-14 01:17:46.705 hoge[23606:1084831] Unknown class ViewController in Interface Builder file.
2015-11-14 01:17:49.311 hoge[23606:1084831] Unknown class ViewController2 in Interface Builder file.
```

How can I solve them?
Source codes are [here](https://github.com/ky0on/SwiftTest).

I'm using XCode Version 7.1.1 (7B1005).

---

SOLVED: I moved the directory to `~/Desktop`, and finally it runs. Very strange...

The same issue reported in [Unknown class in Interface Builder file. Xcode 6 and Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26817036/unknown-class-in-interface-builder-file-xcode-6-and-swift)

Comment: Just restart Xcode and set the classes again in storyboard file.

Comment: Naming classes to something more meaningful avoids such confusions ;-)

Comment: Sorry, there was the copy/paste error in the class name of ```ViewController2.swift```.  fixed.

Answer (score 4):

Select your view controller in you IB and give the correct class name in the custom class field . Remove the view controller and just type in the class name, `xcode` should automatically suggest the available Class name. Then it should be fine!!!

[image]

This was the error :

[image]

Then I removed the class name view controller, and re entered it again, then I didnt get the error:

[image]

If you look carefully, module name is changed to hoge!!! Previously it was none!!!

Comment: why the downvote? I downloaded his source code and run the project. The only issue lies in the IB custom class field.

Comment: The custom class field takes a class not a file name. Answer is wrong it works in your case because there happens to be a class called `viewController` so instead of a crash it's a bug with the view pointing to the wrong class.

Comment: May be thw wording is wrong. I meant the class name only. Thanks for the comment!!!

Comment: BTW the source code link he provided in the question doesnt have the problem as you stated in your answer !!! @Mika

Comment: Then  your screenshot should show `viewController2` and he needs to fix the class :)

Comment: Then your screenshot should show `viewController2` and he does not need to fix the class :-P

Comment: He named it correctly for the view controller 2, did u look into the source code ? @Mika

Comment: OK OK I removed the vote from your edited answer... I just answered the question he asked here. I did not download the project...

Comment: im glad u mentioned the reason you downvote....i really appreciate that!!! I edited my answer, and u took ur down vote back!!! Everything is fair!!!

Comment: I got scared... Phillip is on your team :)

Comment: Was jocking see his comment on my answer!

Comment: Even though I type like ```ViewContr``` into Custom Class - Class, XCode doesn't suggest me anything... And of course Module is ```None```` after I type the class name by myself.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you need create 2 class `ViewController` and `ViewController2`
as like image[image]

And then link it like image

[image]

For example code:

```
// ViewController1.swift
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    //your code here...
}
```

and

```
// ViewController2.swift
import UIKit
class ViewController2: UIViewController {
    //your code here...
}
```

Hope i can help u to resolved this problem.

Answer (score 1):

When you assign the custom class name in Interface Builder, choose a module name too.  If it's left as "none", you'll get the results you describe.

Answer (score 0):

both of your classes - although your swift files are named differently - are called `ViewController`. maybe that is the problem?!

after correcting that you should remove the custom classes from the viewcontrollers in storyboard, build the project, insert the custom classes again and build again.